# Why do Extra Function Calls Speed Up a Program in Python?

Tags: performance, function, python-3.3

If I extract a computation and place it in another function shouldn't
the code be slower? Evidently not. Below, I can't believe fun2 is slower
than fun1, because fun1 clearly does more computation. What is going on?
(Maybe I can have functions call functions call function and REALLY speed
up my code.)

---

1. Heading

   ##

   Python code:

   ```
   MAX = 10000000  
   def fun1(): # 4.26 seconds.  
       def multiply (X, Y): # multiply two 2x2 matrices  
           a, b, c, d = X  
           e, f, g, h = Y  
           return a*e+b*g, a*f+b*h, c*e+d*g, c*f+d*h  
       X = [1,2,3,4]  
       Y = [5,6,7,8]  
       for n in range (MAX):  
           Z = multiply (X, Y)             # Make the call  
       return Z  
   #-------------------------------------------------
   def fun2(): # 6.56 seconds.  
       X = [1,2,3,4]  
       Y = [5,6,7,8]  
       for n in range (MAX):  
           Z = X[0]*Y[0] + X[1]*Y[2], \  
               X[0]*Y[1] + X[1]*Y[3], \  
               X[2]*Y[0] + X[3]*Y[2], \  
               X[2]*Y[1] + X[3]*Y[3]  # Don't make the call.  
       return Z
   ```

Comment: When I run the same code and measure the times were very close... one was 4.66 and the other was 4.77. So something with your profiling may be causing the large difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think it might be that

```
a,b,c,d = X
```

and then referencing a,b,c and d directly is faster that referencing X[0] (and so on).

Every index in list is another lookup, while a,b,c,d=X is only one lookup (I think).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out my own question. The function dispensed with square brackets, and that is where the speed increase came from, not from the function call itself. A Python list contains both values and bit-sizes (or addresses, I don't know which). To access x[3], the computer goes to address x reads the address of x[1], moves there, reads the address of x[2], moves there, reads the address of x[3], moves there and finally accesses the value. This takes time and can be speeded up by assigning the list elements to simple identifiers.